# How to connect comments to more than one flow-chart shape in Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio-2010

Today I was constructing a flow-chart in Visio 2010. I linked a Callout to one of the process shapes (rectangles). After a bit I found the comment in the Callout applied to one other rectangle as well. However, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to link a call-out to multiple shapes, if it's even possible at all.

So my question is: "Can I create a comment (preferably a callout) in Visio 2010 that's linked to multiple shapes?"

I'd prefer to use a call-out, but if that's not possible an alternative would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

This may not work for everyone's situation, but I had the same need in a real simple situation.  All I did was copy the first callout, connected it to the other process, and then moved the callout boxes so they were stacked on top of each other. Not elegant, but it worked

Comment: This is the only way I've found (in a current Visio version) - the other answer doesn't appear to work now (no way to connect that I can see)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this in Visio 2013.

1. Create the first callout
2. Add connectors from the callout to the remaining objects
3. Select the callout and the connectors
4. Right click > Group > Group

Now when you move the callout, the lines adjust length as needed and still stay anchored to the callout.

Comment: How do you add connectors from the callout to the remaining shapes? Visio won't do it for me.